# Trying to count the number of data types in a string

Tags: java, string, types, type-conversion, integer

So at the input, a string contains different types of data. Basically, this is a string, int, and float. I check types through `Float.parseFloat()` and `Integer.parseInt()`. the `Integer.parseInt()` works correctly, yet `Float.parseFloat()` includes all the digits that are checked. How to avoid this?

**The problem is that when checking for the float type, it also considers ints (output)**:

- Hello my 50 name 4.5 is James, I 20 years old and I have 5.7 coins
- Float 4
- Int 2
- String 12

```
public class TypeCountString {
    public static void countTypeInString(String string){
        String[] value = string.split(" ");
        float ifFloat;
        int ifInt;
        String ifString;
        int counter = 0;
        // count Floats
        for (String i: value){
            try{
                ifFloat = Float.parseFloat(i);
                counter++;
                continue;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Float " + counter);

        //count ints
        counter = 0;
        for (String i: value){
            try{
                ifInt = Integer.parseInt(i);
                counter++;
                continue;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Int " + counter);

        //counts strings
        String stringOfStrings = string.replaceAll("[0-9.]","");
        stringOfStrings = stringOfStrings.replaceAll("  "," ");
        String[] value2 = stringOfStrings.split(" ");
        System.out.println("String " + value2.length);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "Hello my 50 name 4.5 is James, I 20 years old and i have 5.7 coins";
        System.out.println(string);
        countTypeInString(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that when checking for the float type, it also considers ints(output)" So check your `i` variable for the presence of `.` using `String.indexOf()`?

Comment: Also, what if the comma is at the end of one of your numbers?...

Answer (score 2):

As Integer is a sub-type of Float, Float will count in Integers into your float count. If you solely just want the number of float that is not integer, just take float count minus integer count.

Answer (score 2):

Some tokens (like "50") are parseable both as integer and float. Your code gives both of them a chance, even though your intention is to only count each token as one type or the other (so count "50" as an integer, not as a float).

A simple fix could be to modify your float check to be:

- make sure that `i` can pass `Float.parseFloat()`, *and*
- confirm that `i` contains a decimal point

That code edit could look like this:

```
Float.parseFloat(i);
if (i.contains(".")) {
    counter++;
    continue;
}
```

Or, as a more involved alternative, instead of checking all input tokens for floats, then re-checking all input tokens for integers, I would take a different approach.

First, I would change the code to stop checking the entire input string repeatedly. This is helpful for 2nd part below, but also cleans up an unnecessary inefficiency of re-checking tokens even if you've already identified their data type. If you had a large number of tokens, it's wasteful to try parsing all of them as float, then try all of them as integer, then try a third time to count plain strings.

Second, since you would be checking (and counting) each token only one time, you could:

- check for integer (before float) – if it passes `Integer.parseInt()`, increment that counter and move on to the next token
- if it doesn't parse as integer, make an attempt to parse that token as float – just `Float.parseFloat()` without looking for decimal; if it worked then bump counter, move to next token
- if it doesn't parse as integer or float, you know it's a `String` so simply bump the counter, then next token

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, since `int` is a subset of `float`, you can always parse a string representing an `int` as a `float`, while the opposite is not true. In fact, if the parsing string contains a decimal separator and you attempt to parse it as an `int`, you'll get a `NumberFormatException`.

However, you could use this behavior to your advantage and try to parse each string to the data type with minimal representation (`int`) and gradually increasing it as the parsing fails, until you reach the most generic representation (`String`). In your case, you could start to parse each string to `int`, if it fails proceed to `float` and ultimately to `String` if the `float` parsing doesn't work either.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countTypesInString();
    }

    public static void countTypesInString() {
        String str = "Hello my 50 name 4.5 is James, I 20 years old and i have 5.7 coins";
        String[] vetStr = str.split("\\s+");

        List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Float> listFloat = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : vetStr) {
            try {
                listInt.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            } catch (NumberFormatException exInt) {
                try {
                    listFloat.add(Float.parseFloat(s));
                } catch (NumberFormatException exFloat) {
                    listStr.add(s);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of ints: " + listInt.size() + " => " + listInt);
        System.out.println("Number of floats: " + listFloat.size() + " => " + listFloat);
        System.out.println("Number of strings: " + listStr.size() + " => " + listStr);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Number of ints: 2 => [50, 20]
Number of floats: 2 => [4.5, 5.7]
Number of strings: 12 => [Hello, my, name, is, James,, I, years, old, and, i, have, coins]
```

Side note: for real number representation, the `double` type is a better choice. In fact, by default Java treats every literal representing a real number as a `double` rather than a `float`. In the snippet above I've kept using `float` to maintain my code as close as possible to the original.